# How to get the selected value with es6 onchange

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im using [semantic-ui's react dropdown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown). I cant seem to get the selected value in my function (using redux).

The setup:

**Module:**

```
const types = [ { value: 'Rails', text: 'Rails' }, ... ]

const DropdownMenu = (props) => (
  <Dropdown placeholder='Select...' fluid selection options={types} onChange={(e) => props.backendSelect(e)} />
)
```

**Action:**

```
export const backendSelect = (text) => ({
  type: BACKEND_TYPE_SELECT,
  text,
})
```

**Reducer:**

```
const backendTypeSelect = (state = '', action) => {
  console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case BACKEND_TYPE_SELECT:
      return action.text;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Is my function correct: `onChange={(e) => props.backendSelect(e)}`?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ backendTypeSelect: state.backendTypeSelect })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(<APP>);
```

Comment: DropDown menu retuns two values on change, event and data, you should be using `onChange= {(e, data} => props.backendSelect(e, data)}`. However, you should be using mapDispatchToProps to call the action or `dispatch` . How are you doing it

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using connect properly.

1. You need to dispatch the actions, for that you can use `mapDispatchToProps` with bindActionCreators
2. You are notconnecting it to the component correctly

Code:

```
mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
       backendSelect: bindActionCreators(actions.backendSelect, dispatch)
   }
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(APP);
```

Then try

```
onChange= {(e, data} => props.backendSelect(e, data)}
```

Comment: Ok I'll have a go later and report

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract value from the event like this:

```
onChange={(e) => props.backendSelect(e.target.value)}
```